# Ant Build in Eclipse results in ${src.dir} and I don't know how to resolve it

Tags: java, eclipse

So after adding a new project to my Eclipse environment through Ant, the source folder just shows `${src.dir}` and a small warning sign. The only warning I find in the problems tab is

```
Classpath variable 'JRE_LIB' in project '<projectname>' is deprecated: Use the JRE System Library instead
```

We have no idea how to resolve this.

We've tried compiling the project through cmd ant, which first resulted in a charset error because of UTF-8 (project is encoded in Latin-1) but we managed to fix that, ant can compile it in cmd.

We have also tried changing Eclipse's charset to Latin-1, which didn't work either.

[image: Screenshot of the library with the weird source folder]

Comment: According to the screenshot, you have somehow managed to configure the non-existent folder `${src.dir}` as an source folder (`${src.dir}` looks like an Ant property). The source folder can be configured in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ in the tab _Source_ (which will be persisted in the `.classpath` file, which might have been improperly modified by the Ant script causing this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ANT build file uses the property `${src.dir}` that is either not defined at all or it uses that property in a target that does not depend on the target that defines said property.

Either ensure that `<property name="src.dir" .../>` is defined in your ANT build file and that all targets that use the property depend on the target that defines the property or (if you do not want to specify a `src.dir` property in your build file) invoke ANT with a `-Dsrc.dir=...` command line option. In the latter case you should add a condition to your build file that fails the build if the `src.dir` property is not set.

See the [ANT manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) for more information.

Comment: To add to this, to tie the answer to the question properly: Ant by default deals with the problem of "Somewhere a property was used, e.g. in `<mkdir dir="${src.dir}" />`, but at that time the property had not been defined", is to treat the property as its own value, i.e. that would make a dir actually named `${src.dir}`, braces, dollars, and all. If the underlying FS supports it, which OP's clearly does.